# Run ReactJS based application on ipad Mini

Tags: reactjs, ipad, deployment

I have created a React Application with multiple frontends, I need to run that on my ipad Mini so that I can demo that it works on it. How can I do it, please advise?

I have tried using the IP configuration but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

### First solution (approximate)

You can open such a view called **device mode** in a browser ([chrome example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/)). But keep in mind: This is only intended as a **first-order approximation** of how your page would look and feel like on another device. It is just being simulated and not guaranteed to be exactly the same. Chrome does support `iPad Mini` previews.

### Second solution (accurate)

You would need to use your computers **IP address** in your local network and make sure that your device is on the **same network** as your computer.

On Linux and Mac you can check your IP with `ifconfig` and `ipconfig` on Windows. Once you know the IP address of your computer and your react dev server is running on port `3000` you can access your app with:

```
http://{IP_ADDRESS}:3000
```